# Force parameter of interface method to be a concrete type per class implementation

Tags: c#

Im facing an scenario where I need to create instances of N objects (implementing an interface) and call a method from it who has a parameter that can be different in each class that implements the interface, it's something like this:

```
//Definition
class BaseOutput
{
    public string Result {get; set;}
}

class BaseParam
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class CarParam : BaseParam
{
    public string Wheels {get; set;}
}

class AirPlaneParam : BaseParam
{
    public string Engines {get; set;}
}

interface Vehicle
{
    IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<BaseParam> parameters,
                                object anotherVal);
}

//Implementation
class Car : Vehicle
{
    //Here the parameters type must be restricted to be only of type IEnumerable<CarParam> 
    public IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<BaseParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        //Do something specific to the Car
    }
}

class AirPlane : Vehicle
{
    //Here the parameters type must be restricted to be only of type IEnumerable<AirPlaneParam> 
    public IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<BaseParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        //Do something specific to the AirPlane
    }
}
```

That restriction is needed to prevent any issues with the concrete using of specific properties for each class.

I'll appreciate your help

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead? Have you considered marking your `Base` classes `abstract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use two prototypes

My suggestion is to use two method prototypes for `Run()`, exposing a different prototype depending on what the caller is doing. This way you can offer both a type-safe and generic version of `Run()`.

**Explanation**

The problem is you have two conflicting requirements:

1. You want to be able to treat all vehicles the same, i.e. store them in a `List<Vehicle>` and be able to iterate through them and call the `Run()` method on each.
2. You want each vehicle type to only allow certain types of parameters, i.e. you want different compile-time rules for each type of vehicle. Thus you actually do *not* want to be able to iterate through them and run `Run()` on each identically; in fact you specifically want a compile time error.

This sound very contradictory, but there is some magic you can do to make something somewhat sensible and reasonably safe.

**Solution details**

The solution I would suggest is to implement `Run()` twice:

1. Implement a specific version of `Run()` in the class's default interface
2. Implement a generic version of `Run()` explicitly in the Vehicle interface. If you don't know what this means, see this question: [What's the difference between implementing an Interface explicitly or implicitly?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136319/whats-the-difference-between-implementing-an-interface-explicitly-or-implicitly).
3. Call the former from the latter, filtering the input as needed (e.g. using [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)).

For example:

```
class AirPlane : Vehicle
{
    IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Vehicle.Run(IEnumerable<BaseParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        return Run(parameters.OfType<AirPlaneParam>(), anotherVal);
    }
    public IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<AirPlaneParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        //Your implementation
    }
}
```

Now you can have your cake and eat it too:

```
var baseParameters = new List<BaseParam>();
var airPlaneParameters = new List<AirPlaneParam>();
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

foreach (Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)
{
    vehicle.Run(baseParameters, "Foo");      //Works, although only airplane parameters will get processed
    vehicle.Run(airPlaneParameters, "Foo");  //Works, due to generic covariance
}

foreach (AirPlane airplane in vehicles.OfType<AirPlane>())
{
    airplane.Run(baseParameters, "Foo"); //Does not compile
    airplane.Run(airPlaneParameters, "Foo"); //Works
}
```

And here is a link to the [working code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V58SGd).

Comment: Im not getting the whole idea behind the way the interface should be defined, could you please add how the interface should look like?

Comment: The interface hasn't changed. I've added a link to a full working example of the code so you can see how to put it together.

Comment: I saw it and got the idea, let me ask you something, what if the Run parameter is a single item instead of a list? Oftype will not work...

Comment: Depends on the specifics. For example, if Vehicle takes an int but Car needs a string, you could just pass `parameter.ToString()`. Hopefully there is *some* way to map the generic parameters onto the specific method; if there isn't, the whole concept behind a common Vehicle interface is not correct for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the parameter type *generic*.

```
interface Vehicle<in TParam> where TParam : BaseParam
{
    IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<TParam> parameters,
                                object anotherVal);
}

//Implementation
class Car : Vehicle<CarParam>
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<CarParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        //Do something specific to the Car
    }
}

class AirPlane : Vehicle<AirPlaneParam>
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseOutput> Run(IEnumerable<AirPlaneParam> parameters, object anotherVal)
    {
        //Do something specific to the AirPlane
    }
}
```

This will restrict what you can pass in:

```
new Car().Run(new CarParam[0], new object()); // allowed
new Car().Run(new BaseParam[0], new object()); // compile-time error
new Car().Run(new AirPlaneParam[0], new object()); // compile-time error
```

Where you'll find difficulty is if you ever need to represent a bunch of vehicles without knowing their generic type:

```
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle<BaseParam>>();
vehicles.Add(new Car()); // compile-time exception.
```

Comment: Im trying to create another class that will hold a property of type IEnumerable<Vehicle<BaseParam>>, but Im getting an error in the property definition, says there is no implicit reference conversion between Vehicle<BaseParam> and IEnumerable<Vehicle<BaseParam>> No idea what to do

Comment: @AnonDev: You're trying to put a single vehicle on something that's meant to hold an IEnumerable of vehicles. You can try wrapping it in a list or an array. But I explicitly warned you that this isn't going to end well for you because a `Vehicle<CarParam>` is not a `Vehicle<BaseParam>`. Trying to put a Car or Plane in your collection is going to fail.